# Check mark escapes checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm trying to write CSS code to mimic and style a checkbox because an `input type="checkbox"` cannot be stylized.

Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
label > input[type="checkbox"] + span::before {
    content: "✓";
    width: 20pt;
    height: 20pt;
    border-radius: 10%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.1rem;
    border-color: gray;

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pos[]" value="shirt" />
    <span> shirt </span>
    <br>
</label>
```

The behavior I want is:

- Empty square is vertically centered
- Checkmark goes inside square

The square is centered, but the checkmark "✓" stays at the bottom and is on the same level with the text that comes to the right of the checkbox. I have tried different combinations of `display` and `vertical-align` but nothing has worked. How can I center the checkmark?

Comment: "an input type="checkbox" cannot be stylized" --- technically they can be, you just need to set `appearance: none;` on them first (and some browsers might not like it)

Comment: I also think there's other CSS at play here, as I get [this](https://i.imgur.com/FQHIGAS.png) when trying it out, which starts to look half-decent once a `text-align: center` is chucked in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text-align: center` to align center horizantally and `line-height: {number}px` to align vertically. I'd suggest you to use [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to manage alignment more efficiently. But for your example you can follow my sample:

```css
label > input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label > input[type="checkbox"] + span::before {
    content: "✓";
    width: 20pt;
    height: 20pt;
    border-radius: 10%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.1rem;
    border-color: gray;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    


} 

label > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span::before {
 content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pos[]" value="shirt" />
    <span> shirt </span>
    <br>
</label>
```

Comment: This `line-height: 28px;` seem to do the job, but I will have to study the flex-box for something permanent.

Comment: Yes, I strongly suggest you to do so. Happy coding @ToniAz !

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should be like this

```css
label > input[type="checkbox"] + span {
    position: relative;
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0.1rem;
    border-color: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
} 
label > input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none
} 
label > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span::before {
    content: "✓";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
} 
label  {
  padding
}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pos[]" value="shirt" />
    <span></span>
    <span> shirt </span>
    <br>
</label>
```